# Binding to static class property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textblock

I want to bind a textblock text to a property of a static class. Whenever the property value of the static class changes, it should reflect to the textblock which is on the other window or custom control.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can bind to ANY property on a static class using the [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) markup extension but if thy do not implement any change tracking, it might cause errors on the refresh!

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:Environment.MachineName}}" />
```

Comment: That is, the property setter needs to raise the PropertyChanged event, just like any bound properties, to refresh properly.

Comment: you need to add "xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" to your <Window> tag in order to make the code snipplet work, otherwise the namespace "sys" is not defined

Comment: @AlexPaven: When invoking the PropertyChanged event, what do we send as the `sender` parameter? null?

Comment: In general for a static property? Sure I guess null would be appropriate; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519386/static-property-using-inotifypropertychanged-c-sharp

Comment: Even if static property notifications are implemented, `Source+x:Static` doesn't enable notifications, you have to use `Path`: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:Foo.StaticBar)}"/>`

Answer (score 24):

For those who use nested static classes to organize/seperate constants. If you need to Bind into nested static classes, It seems you need to use a plus (+) operator instead of the dot (.) operator to access the nested class:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static namespace:StaticClass+NestedStaticClasses.StaticVar}}
```

Example:

```
public static class StaticClass
    {
        public static class NestedStaticClasses
        {
            public static readonly int StaticVar= 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: This helps me a lot, thanks! Any link to official document where is this described?

Answer (score 20):

This has worked for me:

```
Text="{Binding Source={x:Static MyNamespace:MyStaticClass.MyProperty}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Without `Mode=OneWay` I got an exception.

Comment: This method technically works for me, with a strange error. When I use a snippet like this it says that my static class is not part of the namespace (which it is) which gives me `xaml` an "Invalid Markup" screen on the designer. The strange part is that when I run the program it does not error out. Not only that but the snippet that is showing the error is working perfect. any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: @ARidder101 No idea. Sorry. It's been a while since I dealt with this. But it could be simply some bug in the intellisense.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me!

When you have static class with static property like this

```
 namespace App.Classes
 {
     public static class AppData
     {
         private static ConfigModel _configModel;
         public static ConfigModel Configuration
         {
            get { return _configModel; }
            set { _configModel = value; }
         }
     }

     public class ConfigModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

          private bool _text = true;
          public bool Text
          {
               get { return _text ; }
               set { 
                     _text = value; 
                     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
               }
          }
      }
}
```

You can bind it to xaml like this.

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:App.Classes"

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Static c:AppData.Configuration}}"/>
```