# Bind to result of static class' method

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following:

```
namespace Foo {
  public static class Bar {
    public static int Fubar() {
      return 100;
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm in xaml.  I want to use that method to set the height of my rectangle.

```
<Rectangle Height="{Binding Source=???}">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding to static class property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862455/binding-to-static-class-property)... but you'd have know that and saved time if you just typed your question title into a search engine first.

Comment: Why on earth would you title your question '*WPF bind to property of static class*' when you want to '*bind to a method of a static class*'?

Comment: This question is asking how to bind to a static class *method*, while the linked question is asking how to bind to a static class *property*. There is a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ObjectDataProvider to bind to a method.

Example (adjust to your NameSpace / Class / Method):

```
<Window x:Class="SerialPortBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ports="clr-namespace:System.IO.Ports;assembly=System"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type ports:SerialPort}" 
            MethodName="GetPortNames" x:Key="portNames"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource portNames}}"/>
</Window>
```

The assembly portion of the xmnls at the top may not be needed; ignore it if it does not come up in CodeSense.

Comment: -1 That's not true at all... the user does *not* need to do that... they can just use the `x:Static` notation shown by @AjS.

Comment: The OP is binding to a static property, not to a method. How does your code help with that?

Comment: +1 Apologies @doerig, I did not notice that the question author actually wanted to bind to the output of a method seeing as their title was named *WPF bind to property of static class*. I had to edit your answer before I could remove my down vote so I just reformatted one line.

Comment: @DanPuzey, please take another look at this... I think that you made the same mistake as me due to this stupidly titled question.

Comment: @Sheridan/doerig: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Indeed, doerig's answer is correct (and the question needs editing!). My apologies!

Comment: ups, I should have pointed out that there was an error in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
{Binding Source={x:Static classnamespace:Bar}, Path=Fubar}
```

Comment: "The namespace prefix 'classnamespace' is not defined"

Comment: You should declare that in your xaml:-xmlns:mynamespace="clr-namespace:ApplicationName" Here ApplicationName is name of the namespace.  {Binding Source={x:Static mynamespace:Bar}, Path=Fubar}