# binding to a property of another class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following **ViewModel**:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public ObservableCollection<A> MyCollection { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand Command1{ get; set; }

    public ViewModel() {
        Command1= new RelayCommand(Method1);
    }

    void Method1() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And this **View**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TemplateEditor.Views.View"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TemplateEditor.ViewModels"
DataContext="{DynamicResource ViewModel}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    ...

    <Button DataContext="{StaticResource FormIdBlockViewModel}"  Content="qwe" Command="{Binding Command1}" />

    ...
</UserControl>
```

The button works fine in this case, but I want to move all commands into a certain file. So, if I create **AppCommands.cs** file:

```
public class AppCommands
{
    private static RelayCommand Command1 { get; set; }

    static AppCommands()
    {
        Command1 = new RelayCommand(Method1);
    }

    public static void Method1(object parameter)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Also, I change **View**:

```
...
xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:TemplateEditor.Common"
...
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    <commands:AppCommands x:Key="AppCommands"/>

...

<Button DataContext="{StaticResource AppCommands}" Content="qwe" Command="{Binding Command1}"  />
```

The command does not work.

Could you please to advise how to perform binding to `AppCommands.Commands`?

Comment: Acc to me, you should get compile time error at  "public static void Method1(object parameter)" , didn't you get it?

Comment: No, I do not get any errors.

Comment: RelayCOmmand would not allow you to have method with parameter, since it expects an Action()

Comment: Why is your Command private? Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862455/binding-to-static-class-property)?

Comment: Rest of the things works fine for me with Command={Binding Command1,Source={StaticResource AppCommands}}.

Comment: `Command1` is a private static property. You cannot bind to it by pulling from an instance of `AppCommands`. You can just set the `Command` to the static property (requiring public) like this `Command="{x:Static commands:AppCommands.Command1}"`

Comment: @DanielCastro OMG! It is my big mistake that Command1 is private. I just did it public and it works fine! Thank you!