# Unable to successfully dynamically bind IsVisible to static field

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

I am trying to do something similar to *[Binding to static class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862455/binding-to-static-class-property)*. I want to bind the *IsVisible* property of multiple controls to a single static *bool* (so I can make them all appear and disappear with a single C# statement).

Here is my XAML for one of the controls:

```html
<Label Grid.Row="3"
       x:Name="LabelDireWarning"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       TextColor="Red"
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
       IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Static local:State.IsChangingPassword}}"
       Text="blah blah."/>
```

Here is the field:

```csharp
public static class State
{
    public static bool IsChangingPassword = true;
    etc.
```

I have a test button that toggles `IsChangingPassword`, but the visibility of the control does not change.

I guess this has to do with "the raising of the `PropertyChanged` event," but what should I to do?

Comment: you can only bind to public properties, not fields

Comment: `public bool IsChangingPassword { get; set; }= true;`

Comment: and, if you want to dynamically update at runtime you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: The static binding to a field (as opposed to a property) worked just fine (other than that the relationship was "one-time").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the new features in WPF 4.5 that it is supporting for binding to static properties. It may not work for `Xamarin.Forms`.

And as [Jason said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477677/unable-to-successfully-dynamically-bind-isvisible-to-static-field#comment121021193_68477677), you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want to dynamically update at run time. But in forms, the static class could not implement the interface.

So you should make some changes:

```csharp
public static class State
{

    private static Status g_Current = new Status();

    public static Status Current
    {
        get
        {
            return g_Current;
        }
    }

    public class Status : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public  event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private  bool _isChangingPassword = true;

        public  bool IsChangingPassword
        {
            get { return _isChangingPassword; }

            set
            {
                if (value != _isChangingPassword)
                {
                    _isChangingPassword = value;

                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChangingPassword");
                }
            }
        }


        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In your XAML:

```xml
<Label Grid.Row="3"
       x:Name="LabelDireWarning"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       TextColor="Red"
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
       IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Static local:State.Current}, Path=IsChangingPassword}"
       Text="blah blah."/>
```

And then when you could change the `IsChangingPassword` in your code-behind like:

```csharp
State.Current.IsChangingPassword = false;
```